# Syntax error trying to authenticate / init IBM Watson service in SDK

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, watson-discovery

I am trying to run sample code that uses an IBM Watson service. After setting my username / password or the IAM key as required, the code fails. In Python it is an error like this:

> **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iam_apikey'

What is the reason? What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you ran into an issue with the Watson SDK. Recently, with the [Python SDK V4](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk) and the [Node SDK V5](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk), they introduced a breaking change ([Python](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/MIGRATION-V4.md), [Node](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/MIGRATION-V5.md)) which I found in their [release notes](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/releases). There is a new, more abstract authentication mechanism that caters to different authentication types. You would need to slightly change the code for how NLC is initialized.

This is from the [Python migration instructions](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/MIGRATION-V4.md):

> For example, to pass a IAM apikey:

**Before**

```
from ibm_watson import MyService

service = MyService(
    iam_apikey='{apikey}',
    url='{url}'
)
```

**After(V4.0)**

```
from ibm_watson import MyService
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('{apikey}')
service = MyService(
    authenticator=authenticator
)
service.set_service_url('{url}')
```

See some of the [IBM Cloud core SDKs for more documentation](https://github.com/IBM?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=core&type=&language=), e.g., here is the [Authentication doc](https://github.com/IBM/node-sdk-core/blob/master/AUTHENTICATION.md) for the core Node SDK.